# Undefined namespace prefix on previously working SPARQL query

Tags: namespaces, sparql, dbpedia

I am interested in the geographic coordinates of banks, central banks, financial institutions, universities and colleges. This is my query:

```sql
SELECT ?label ?lat ?long
WHERE {
  {?x dct:subject category:International_finance_institutions } UNION
  {?x dct:subject category:Federal_Reserve_Banks } UNION 
  {?x dct:subject category:Central_banks } UNION 
  {?x a <http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity> }.
     ?x geo:lat ?lat .
     ?x geo:long ?long .
     ?x rdfs:label ?label.
        FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) 
}
```

Exactly this code worked (last download: June 21st, 2015). This morning however I keep getting this error: `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 5: Undefined namespace prefix at 'category' before '}'`. I was checking [the list of predefined namespaces](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl), but all seems correct. What's wrong with `category`? BTW: I also tried other codes offered on this side, and some are also not working. Did the virtuoso guys change something?

Comment: **I was checking the list of predefined namespaces, but all seems correct. What's wrong with category?**  On the list of prefixes that you linked to, the only mention of "category" is in the prefix `dct` for  `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:`.  As Artemis noted, the predefined namespaces have changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have changed the [namespaces](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl]). so you need to change `category:` to `dbc:`.

```
SELECT ?label ?lat ?long
WHERE {
  {?x dct:subject dbc:International_finance_institutions } UNION
  {?x dct:subject dbc:Federal_Reserve_Banks } UNION 
  {?x dct:subject dbc:Central_banks } UNION 
  {?x a <http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity> }.
     ?x geo:lat ?lat .
     ?x geo:long ?long .
     ?x rdfs:label ?label.
    FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) 
}
```